# Kohana3 ORM Relationship Clarification needed

Tags: orm, kohana-3

Have another problem with ORM.

I have three models: user.php, tag.php and /user/tag.php.

> **user.php**
>    name
>    pass
>
> **tag.php**
>   name
>   slug
>
> **/user/tag.php**
>   id
>   tag_id
>   user_id

I created has many relation between user and user_tag model. So I'm getting users tags using following code:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
$tags = $user->tags->find_all();
```

And here's my question, is it possible to build relation that will be automatically query for tags names too (or should I use join() or leave ORM and take query builder for this)?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a [has_many through relationship](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through):

```
$protected $_has_many = array(
   'tags' => array(
      'model'   => 'tag',
      'through' => 'user_tag',
   ),
);
```

So, `$user->tags->find_all()` will return an array of `Model_Tag` objects.